# When someone says that someone is like another person, do they mean the have a similar appearance or personality?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Let's say someone says ***you are like your father***, do they mean that I look like my dad or that I have a similar personality. Can it mean both?

Comment: I'd say it refers to your personality. If it is about your appearance I'd say : " you look like your  father " . If you use "resemble" I think it could refer to either your personality or your appearance.

Comment: I agree with @anouk.  I think most native speakers would understand "you are like your father" to mean "you behave/act like your father" or "you and your father have a similar personality".  In my opinion, using the word "resemble" is more likely to be understood as "look like".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be like someone usually refers to personality (behavior), not looks.

- He is like his father. [refers to personality or tastes or preferences]

UNLESS specifically described
- He is like his father. He has big ears.

- **For looks**, we say:

**He looks lik**e his father.

- For the voice or comments:

**He sounds like** his father.

- For appearing to be like:

**He appears to be like** his father.
**He seems to be like** his father.

appear or seem refers also the personality, not physical looks.